# Not able to link elemantor form to hubspot

Tags: wordpress, elementor, hubspot

I have a normal elemantor form with Recaptcha enabled and for some reason, Hubspot is not recognizing the form as a non-hubspot form. I am using Form Vibes for the form along with front end validation

I tried the following solutions but it still didn't help:

1. https://elementor.com/help/hubspot-elementor-integration/
2. Disabled Recaptcha
3. Created a new form with no validation and unliked from form vibes.

The form submits without returning any errors but unfortunately, Hubspot does not recognize it.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
I had this happen many times. Try disabling / enabling the hubspot plugin.
In the end I created APIs for each of the form as their plugin is very buggy.

Is the form recognised in the hubspot plugin?

Comment: Thank you for replying, The form is not recognised in hubspot plugin. And I tried disabling and enabling it and found no luck. I wouldnt mind creating an API for each of the form but I am not able to find the right source for it.